# iOS UIWebView - trap exceptions loading invalid file format

Tags: objective-c, ios, exception, uiwebview

I have a UIViewController containing a UIWebView which I am using to view various documents.  Occasionally a document may attempt to be loaded which is not supported by the UIWebView (e.g. old Excel 2.0 sheet).  Currently this causes output in the debug window as follows :

**exception: CPMessageException: The file format is invalid.**

**EXCEPTION CPMessageException: (null)**

The webViewDidStartLoad method fires, but neither webViewDidFinishLoad or didFailLoadWithError fires.

The error doesn't crash the app, but I would like to trap this exception to provide my own message for the user.  Can anybody suggest how to trap and handle this?

Many thanks,
Jonathan

Comment: None of the above fires because the exception did fire. Perhaps you can use \@try ... \@catch to solve this.

Comment: Hi, I already tried using @try..@catch around the [webView loadRequest:] method but no exception gets caught.  As I say it doesn't actually cause the app to crash.

Comment: Please go to Product > Edit Scheme.. > Diagnostics Tab > Tick Enable Zombie Objects  and show crash log to us with your line of code that issue has been happened

Comment: Hi, sorry I've done this but there is no crash log as the app doesn't stop working.  The last lines that are executed are : NSURL *sMyURL = [NSURL URLWithString:sLocalDocumentURL];  [uiwebDocumentView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:sMyURL]];

Comment: use abort() to force a crash (and therefore a crash log)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately CPMessageException is part of the private frameworks of Apple, in case of office files, OfficeImport.framework. This is thrown when the framework receives an unusable file.

The reason your application is not crashing is because it is probably being handled in the import code itself. Even setting NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler will not work (as I have tried in the past).

The best way to go around this would be to use the shouldStartLoadWithRequest delegate method of UIWebView:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Here you could preemptively stop the file from being loaded into the web view and avoid a clueless blank screen.

(Am not sure if there is a way to read NSLog output on the fly so you could monitor it. But that is probably not a right way to do it!)

Update: Just filed a bug regarding this. Let us see what the Apple Developers have to say on this.